# What is the meaning of the term "motivic"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm looking for a simpler explanation of the idea behind [motives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motive_(algebraic_geometry)), and a quick overview of applications.

One particular question is the meaning of the term "motivic" (which I've seen multiple times applied to different nouns, i.e. "motivic periods", "a [certain theory has a] motivic core", etc)

The Wikipedia article is unfortunately too unclear and convoluted for me to properly understand it. Introductory references will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For "motivic periods" see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06410).  The author admits himself:"We shall use the adjective ‘motivic’ for such a period, although
much of this paper is in fact Hodge-theoretic." The Wikipedia article gives in fact a survey. I am not sure that one can do much better without loosing the mathematical content.

Comment: Lately, Terry Tao had blog about a unification of cohomologies (aka Prismatic cohomology) where "motivic" approach is described as an approach "to be able to define cohomology $H^i(X/\overline{A}, A)$ for varieties $X$ (or similar objects) defined over arbitrary commutative rings $\overline{A}$, and with coefficients in another arbitrary commutative ring $A$. " https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/03/19/prismatic-cohomology/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take whatever I write with a lot of care, I do not guarantee completeness or correctness, and I welcome any corrections.

The issue is that motives have been around for quite some time (I would guess roughly 60 years now) and there is not even a complete definition that satisfies everybody. But there are a lot of conjectures on magic properties that they should have, and quite some evidence that research is indeed on the right track. Motives have been introduced by Grothendieck in the '60s because people realized that a "universal cohomology theory" for algebraic varieties could help to solve the standard conjectures about algebraic cycles (which are still open). The idea was that motives should contain the "essential core" of varieties and provide such a theory, but there was no satisfying definition of them. From then, various approaches have been studied. I will mention two, which are not necessarily the most relevant. Nori defined a category that could be the right one, but it is still not proved whether it satisfies all the required properties. Other people (notably Voevodsky) found a category which should be the derived category of the category of motives, if this exists. Even without the actual category of motives, one can do quite some things with derived categories, so they are actually useful. In an ideal world, it will be proved that the two approaches are just different points of view, and for some very special cases this has actually been proved ($1-$motives, for instance).

Motivic periods are, roughly speaking, the complex numbers that one obtains "integrating on motives". Some motives correspond to varieties and one just gets the periods obtained from integrating algebraic differential forms on that variety, but working with (whatever category) of motives is more general and sometimes easier.

Depending on your background, you might find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlJIECqRZRA) series of 4 lectures interesting. You will not learn everything about motives, but Brown is a great mathematician who masters both the mathematical aspects and the applications of motivic periods to physics, so his talks are really interesting in any case. As Dietrich Burde pointed out in a comment, some of his articles could also be interesting for you.

I don't think that there is a satisfying definition of what "motivic" means in full generality :)

The book "Une introduction aux motifs" by Yves André is also a very good reference, but it is probably not available in English.

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28803/what-is-the-proper-initiation-to-the-theory-of-motives-for-a-new-student-of-alge) is a related question on MathOverflow which might give you some more ideas.

In any case, keep in mind that motives are quite an advanced topic, so an easy introduction might not exist. If you find one, let me know, I would be interested as well ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! I'm a big fan of "learning by example" – could you maybe extend your answer to include one that is nontrivial, but still simple? I get it – motives are basically algebraic curves together with algebraic volume forms on them? So e.g. in 1 complex dimension, a unit circle and the ordinary volume  form form a motive with period $2\pi$, right?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus $2\pi i$ :) Yes, roughly, but you also need a path, and moreover motives can come from varieties in every dimension. But if you take $1-$motives, then you have those coming from curves. The nice thing about them is that, as far as I know, all the different approaches have been proved to be equivalent for them. If you're interested in periods, you might want to have a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10104) article. In the introduction there are some remarks about motives in general, and somewhere there are some computations of periods of $1-$motives.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Sorry, actually I misread, this is not quite correct. A single motive can have loads of periods. At least is some settings, a motive is, roughly, a variety (or a "piece" of it, or even something more general) together with a "singular homology" (space of cycles) and a "de Rham cohomology" (space of differential forms) that become isomorphic after tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$ (integration pairing). Then a period arises when you choose a cycle and a differential form and integrate.

Comment: For instance, you can have $\mathbb{C}^\times$ with its homology and cohomology as a motive, and if you choose the cycle which circles once around the origin anticlockwise and the differential form $\frac{dz}{z}$ you obtain the period $2 \pi i$. But you can also have more abstruse things that do not directly correspond to varieties. For instance, for $1-$motives, you do have a way to interpret the periods of a curve as periods of a $1-$motive (Lemma 4.9 in the article mentioned above), but you also have many other motives

Comment: Which is useful because they form an abelian category, which allows you to describe in a meaningful way when a period can be zero, or transcendental or what not